# Connect to SQL on a local domain controller using an AD account

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In this example, the code is trying to connect to a local SQL Server database using a predetermined AD account, but the machine is a domain controller.

The following code:

```
using System.Data.SQLClient;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string strSource = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=database;User Id=domain\\user;Password=password;";
    SqlConnection sql4WD = new SqlConnection(strSource);

    sql4WD.Open();
    sql4WD.Close();
}
```

Gives the following error:

```
System.Data.SQLClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'domain\username'.
```

This user is a domain admin and can log into SQL Server Management Studio without any problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use windows authentication, you can't specify a username and password in a connection string. That only works for sql authentication. For windows authentication, you *must* have your process running under the desired user account.